# Case assignment rule does not fire from Community page using global action

Tags: customer-community, assignment-rules

We have a contact support form in customer community using a global action for Case Creation, I can not see the "run assignment rule" option in global action layout like we have at normal page layouts.

We have achieved this via trigger by adding the dmlOptions, but I am wondering if there is a OOTB way to run assignment rules when we create Cases using Community Contact Support form.
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, this is a known limitation, you can also use a PB + invocable Apex to solve this; see also this [appexchange (free) product](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000ErILmUAN)

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me before when sandbox is refreshed. Just one more thing to check on the case page layout of that record type.
Go to layout Properties and make sure the default is checked for Case Assignment Checkbox.If it still doesn't work, check if off, save, then check it on and save it again. 
[image]

Comment: This layout properties is not actually making any impact on Community Page, probably this is because the global action is involved and there is no Layout properties on global action.

Comment: still, that global action create a case of certain record type. Could you check the layout property of that case record type? Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

There is an SF Idea post here - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A00000159FNQAY and here - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5Z0AAI which is related to your post. Always worth a vote!